# API call with file attachment

Tags: java

My program will do a folder monitoring(source folder ) for any incoming new file, if there's any incoming new file, it's will detect the new file coming and move to another directory which is folder destination. Before it's move to the destination folder, it's will check the file status to determine the completion of the file copy status. For my own testing purpose, i used copy and paste to the source folder. Everything went good until the file being move to the destination folder,my program will took the file from destination folder and send it via API call but i am getting this error message in my compiler

```
The new file in source folder :pdf-sample.pdfEvent :ENTRY_CREATE
Start checking the file copy status
In Copy ProcessC:\User\source\pdf-sample.pdf (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
In Copy ProcessC:\User\source\pdf-sample.pdf (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
In Copy ProcessC:\User\source\pdf-sample.pdf (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
In Copy ProcessC:\User\source\pdf-sample.pdf (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
In Copy ProcessC:\User\source\pdf-sample.pdf (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
In Copy ProcessC:\User\source\pdf-sample.pdf (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
In Copy ProcessC:\User\source\pdf-sample.pdf (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
In Copy ProcessC:\User\source\pdf-sample.pdf (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
Finish copy

File size :7945

File Name :pdf-sample.pdf
Start to copy file to destination folder
Completed
file size in destination folder:7945
file name in destination folder:pdf-sample.pdf
file dir :C://REST API//destination//pdf-sample.pdf
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Header.addField(Lorg/apache/james/mime4j/parser/Field;)V
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart.addField(FormBodyPart.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart.generateContentDisp(FormBodyPart.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart.<init>(FormBodyPart.java:64)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addPart(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:116)
    at fileStatus.fileStatus.pass(fileStatus.java:252)
    at fileStatus.fileStatus.main(fileStatus.java:81)
```

Here is my code for moving the file to destination folder, the following code will check the status of file(In progress of copy or finish copy), The **pass()** method will pass the file name and file size for indicate which file that need to send into the server via API call

```
                while(true)
                    {
                        File file = new File(FilePath);
                        if ( file.exists())
                        {
                            RandomAccessFile statusCheck = null;
                                try 
                                {
                                    statusCheck = new RandomAccessFile(file,"r");
                                    if(statusCheck != null)
                                    {
                                        long filebyte = file.length();
                                        String filename = file.getName();
                                        System.out.println("Finish copy");
                                        System.out.println("\nFile size :"+filebyte);
                                        System.out.println("\nFile Name :"+filename);
                                        statusCheck.close();
                                        Path source = Paths.get(FilePath);
                                        Path destination = Paths.get("C://REST API//destination");
                                       System.out.println("Start to copy file to destination folder");
                                       Files.move(source, destination.resolve(source.getFileName()));
                                       System.out.println("Completed");
                                       fileStatus fs = new fileStatus();   //line 80
                                       fs.pass(filebyte, filename);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("In Copy Process" + e.getMessage());

                                }
                               }
                   }
```

This is my code for the **pass()** method

```
private void pass(long filesize, String filename) 
    {
        {
             String dir = "C://REST API//destination//";
             String Finalfile = dir.concat(filename);
             System.out.println("file size :" +filesize);
             System.out.println("file name :" +filename);
             System.out.println("file dir :" +Finalfile);
              HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.27:8008/file");  //remote API URL 
                FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(Finalfile));  // take the file from directory 
            //    ArrayList ArrList = new ArrayList(1);
            //    ArrList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(bin));
                 HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()  // build require argument 
                           .addPart("file",bin)
                           .build(); 
                post.addHeader("filename", Finalfile);  
                post.setEntity(reqEntity);  // send via post method 
                HttpResponse response = null;
```

From the error message in my compiler, it's show that the line 81 and 252 having problem which is **HttpEntity** and **pass()** method parameter. Anyone know what is my mistake? i had included httpmine 4.3.6 jar but it's also not working

Comment: Might be a versioning problem.

Comment: Any version that's compatible ? i had tested the HTTP post before i add in the file status check and it's working

Comment: Please strucutre your code in small methods, post ENTIRE and FOMRATTED code, don't cut it in the meddle of the method code. This is good advice, generally more important for You and your careera than the problem you're trying to solve.